# Cumulative sum based on another dataframe column without itertuples?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I can't wrap my head around solving this problem without itertuples

I want to take mean values from every row that the cumulative adds up to less than 1/3rd of total sum of a different column

Starting dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'model_1': [0.15, 0.19, 0.25, 0.54, 0.55 , 0.98, 1.12],
                   'model_2': [0.12, 0.13, 0.32, 0.45, 0.6 , 0.7, 1.05],
                   'exposure': [0.4, 1, 1.6, 1, 2, 2, 3],
                   'target': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 1.1]})
```

Here we see that the sum of the exposure is 11, and my intention is to make 3 buckets, take the mean value of all of the rows that have a cumulative sum less than or equal to 1/3 of the total exposure

So we can see that the first 4 rows have a cumulative sum of 4, then I want to take a relative mean of those columns.

This means the first value in aggr_model_1 is:

```
((0.15 * 0.4) + (0.19 * 1) + (0.25 * 1.6) + 0.54)/4 = 0.2975
```

This same process is then applied for aggr_model_2 and aggr_target

Output dataframe:

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame({'aggr_model_1': [0.2975, 0.765, 1.12],
                          'aggr_model_2': [0.285, 0.65, 1.05],
                          'aggr_exposure': [4, 4, 3],
                          'aggr_target': [0.28, 0.65, 1.1]})
```

Comment: Could you adjust your example to emphasize the 1/3 thing? I can't understand it from the text, and your current `output_df` can be obtained by a simple `df.groupby('exposure').mean()`.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Basically in my real data the exposure values are more varied. My intention is to group up the data based on the sum of the exposure. So it needs to take the mean of multiple rows but doing so by adding each value to the total where the current cumulative sum is less than the target cumulative sum (in this case 1/3 of the total).  I will make an adjustment to the dataframes to more clearly explain

Comment: @psarka fixed the body to hopefully make it more interpretable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a shot, see if I understood it right. Ingredients of this computation are:

- total exposure, which we can compute as `total = df.exposure.sum()`
- bins dividing the total exposure into 3 parts `bins = np.linspace(0, total, 4)`
- cumulative exposure, which is `cum_exposure = df.exposure.cumsum()`
- binned cumulative exposure `bin_cum_exposure = pd.cut(cum_exposure, bins)`
- exposure weighted observations `w_model_1 = df.exposure * df.model_1`
- mean! `df.groupby('bin_cum_exposure').w_model_1.mean()`

Putting things together:

```py
total = df.exposure.sum()
bins = np.linspace(0, total, 4)

(df.assign(bin_cum_exposure = lambda x: pd.cut(x.exposure.cumsum(), bins),
           w_model_1 = lambda x: x.exposure * x.model_1,
           w_model_2 = lambda x: x.exposure * x.model_2,
           w_total = lambda x: x.exposure * x.target)
   .groupby('bin_cum_exposure')
   .mean()
)
```

The answer differs from your manual computation, as the first bin has 3 elements rather than 4 as in your example.